# Android studio keep importing old version of libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Android studio keeps importing old version of libraries even though my gradle are updated.

I'm trying to import the new notification builder
[image: im trying to import the new notification builder]

I'm trying to import the new notification builder but then my project won't give me the updated version of the library

I have these in my gradle :

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

what else am I missing?
why is it keeps importing `25.3.0` library if I have `28.0.0` in my gradle

Comment: Have you synced your gradle file?  Try doing so manually.

Comment: Try to remove the app build and gradle folder and run again.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project to refresh your gradle dependencies. In Android Studio, `Build` > `Clean Project`, and then `Build` > `Rebuild Project`

Comment: still having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try to clean up your `.gradle` and `.idea` directory under your project root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Settings->Editor->General->Auto Import.

1) Remove the check mark from "Add unambiguos imports on the fly".

then in your java class Call the Required Library Class and press Alt+Enter. You can choose which library class to be imported.